# get_browser function "'chromedriver'" error

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have am trying to use Chromedriver for web scraping but am experiencing problems. I was able to successfully install and run chromedriver and specified the executable path using:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/chromedriver")
```

I am also able to run the below code to get to google.com successfully (as a test).

```
driver.get('https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/HubSpot-Reviews-E227605_P1.htm')
```

However, now I have a part of my code that uses the get_browser function, and when I do I receive two errors saying: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver'" and "WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH"

Does anyone know why the get_browser function would cause such an error, even though I already successfully installed chromedriver and defined the path?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either add the chrome driver to your **[system path](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/9bryqd/how_to_put_chromedriver_in_path_for_using/)**, or add `executable_path` to the code - like so:

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')